# In PhpStorm, is there a way to automatically associate a default server with a Git branch?

Tags: php, git, server, phpstorm, branch

I have multiple remote servers, each associated with a different Git branch.  When I switch to a different branch, I want PhpStorm to change the default upload server to something I can associate with the branch.

Is there a way to do this, maybe with Mappings?

I am concerned that I may switch branch and do a file upload and have the file uploaded to the "wrong" server (not the one associated with the branch, but the current default server).

Comment: AFAIK: not possible. You may read what devs are suggestion about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25732

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can:

1. Add a git setting for each branch (that will be used only by you)
2. Write a little script that do the task to read this setting for the current branch and push to this remote (and not 'server' like you name it).
3. Create a git alias that call the script.